CORS issue from React to Flask
I have a project with Flask backend and React frontend, and I'm running into a CORS issue. I wrapped the entire app with CORS(app) which should prevent the CORS issue, and it does work for my sign up and sign in function.
However, one of my React pages has a modal that is supposed to create a client and add them to the database, and it is having the same CORS issue I had when the app wasn't wrapped in CORS(). Is a React Modal treated as a completely different page or something weird?
def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)

    CORS(app)

    db.init_app(app)

    migrate=Migrate(app,db)
    JWTManager(app)

    migrate.init_app(app)

    api = Api(app, version='1.0', title='API', description='API', doc='/docs')

    api.add_namespace(recipe_ns)


    @app.shell_context_processor
    def make_shell_context():
        return {
            'db': db, 
        }

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    
    
    return app

When I try to add a client, it gives me this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/clients' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I tried removing CORS(app), which caused the sign up function to have this same error, but when I added it back the sign up function works as normal, but the add client function still has this error message.
Here is the modal that has the issue:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { addClient } from './api';
import './AddPersonModal.css';

const AddPersonModal = ({ onClose }) => {
  // State for form inputs
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  const [company, setCompany] = useState('');
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [tags, setTags] = useState('');
  const [vendor, setVendor] = useState('');


  // Handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await addClient(firstName, lastName, email, phone, company, address, tags, vendor);

      // window.location.reload();

    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  
  // Add/remove overflow: hidden to/from the body element when the modal is open/closed
  useEffect(() => {
    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    return () => {
      body.style.overflow = '';
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="modal-overlay">
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h4>Add Someone</h4>
          <button className="close-button" onClick={onClose}>
            &times;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="first-name">First Name *</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="first-name"
                value={firstName}
                onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="last-name">Last Name </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="last-name"
                value={lastName}
                onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
              <input
                type="number" 
                id="phone"
                value={phone}
                onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="company">Company Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="company"
                value={company}
                onChange={(e) => setCompany(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="address">Street Address</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="address"
                value={address}
                onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="tags">Tags</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Select or add a tag..."
                value={tags}
                onChange={(e) => setTags(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>      
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="vendor">Vendor</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="vendor"
                value={vendor}
                onChange={(e) => setVendor(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group float-right">
              <button type="submit" className='blue-button btn btn-primary float-right mt-2'>Save</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddPersonModal;


"Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request" is the important part of the error, if you Google that you'll find some possible solutions. E.g. How to resolve 'preflight is invalid (redirect)' or 'redirect is not allowed for a preflight request'. You haven't shown the actual request code but based on the error you might want to try http://localhost:5000/clients/ (with a trailing slash) instead.
